# Neither, or nor, or both

Tags: grammar

I don't have cash, neither do I have means to raise

Or

I don't have cash, nor do I have means to raise

I don't want to use the traditional:

Neither have I cash, nor do I have the means to raise

Comment: I think the idea's a fine and succinct way to use "nor". Perhaps you need two extra words, though: "I don't have cash, nor do I have _the_ means to raise _it_"

Comment: Your "traditional" version is *totally* unidiomatic today, and I don't believe it was ever "normal", even in archaic or poetic contexts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are OK (**Edit**: once corrected as Fumblefingers suggests in a comment to this reply), though for me they are a little literary, which clashes with the colloquial word 'cash'.

I'm not sure if this was just a typo, but I would count your "traditional" sentence as ungrammatical: clause-initial "neither" (like "never" and "so") requires inversion. So "Neither have I" or "Neither do I have".

Comment: I certainly wouldn't say "both are OK" - without the missing article and an additional noun/pronoun referencing whatever can't be raised *(...nor do I have **the** means to raise **it/any [cash]**)* they're completely unacceptable.

Comment: You're right, @FumbleFingers. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 2):

"Nor" can indeed appear in a sentence without "neither". One of the accepted conventions of its such usage is listing of two negations in one sentence and starting the second one with "nor", with a comma before it. Your second example is perfectly OK. Go ahead with it.